# Bootstrap columns height issue. How to set height AUTO for Bootstrap grid columns?

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I'm building a website but I'm having a problem that I need to resolve
You can use the following photos for reference
**We are getting this**
[image]
**We want this.**
[image]

thank you

When we try to make height auto, we get different results.
My Code

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-3">
        Content
        Content
        Content
        Content
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3">
        Content
        Content
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3">
        Content
        Content
        Content
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3">
        Content
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3">
        Content
        Content
        Content
        Content
        Content
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3">
        Content
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3">
        Content
        Content
        Content
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: So, what does the code look like, with which you get the first result? Please update your question and provide the code in a code block.

Comment: In bootstrap 4, use the built-in [`card-columns`](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/components/card/#card-columns) or something external like [masonry](https://masonry.desandro.com/)

Comment: Note that in bootstrap 5, `card-columns` has been removed in favor of pure masonry: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/examples/masonry/

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell you exactly without seeing your source, so I'd recommend you edit that in, if possible.
Triple backticks ``` before and after a block of code will show it nicely with syntax highlighting!

For the actual question, though, here's my best guess as to what's going on, based on similar issues I've seen in the past:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-6">
            <div style="height: 250px" class="card m-2 bg-primary"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-6">
            <div style="height: 100px" class="card m-2 bg-primary"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-6">
            <div style="height: 60px" class="card m-2 bg-primary"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-6">
            <div style="height: 200px" class="card m-2 bg-primary"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

As you may know, Bootstrap uses a "12-column" system for layouts.
Each row contains 12 equal "column-units", that can be divvied out between child columns.
In the above, I'm setting each column to be 6 "column-units" wide (col-6), which means they will each be half of the parent container's width.

That works fine for the first two, but the third won't fit, and needs to overflow.
When a row overflows, in some ways it acts as if you've created a second row to hold the overflow:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-6">
            <div style="height: 250px" class="card m-2 bg-primary"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-6">
            <div style="height: 100px" class="card m-2 bg-primary"></div>
        </div>
        <!-- First row "ends" -->
        <!-- Second row "begins" -->
        <div class="col-6">
            <div style="height: 60px" class="card m-2 bg-primary"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-6">
            <div style="height: 200px" class="card m-2 bg-primary"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

To fix this, you only want one column element for each column you're showing, with all the children of that column inside it:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-6">
            <!-- All elements in the first column should be placed here -->
            <div style="height: 250px" class="card m-2 bg-primary"></div>
            <div style="height: 100px" class="card m-2 bg-primary"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-6">
            <!-- All elements in the second column should be placed here -->
            <div style="height: 60px" class="card m-2 bg-primary"></div>
            <div style="height: 200px" class="card m-2 bg-primary"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The examples above only have two columns, but I put together a simple example using four columns, which you can find [here.](https://www.codeply.com/p/KR2CKYzflI)

For further reading on the Bootstrap 4 grid system, you can see their documentation [here.](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/)